# Does a B7add11 still function like a dominant chord?

Tags: chord-theory

If I take a B7 chord on the guitar in open position and play an open E on the top instead of the fretted F#, I get a B7 add11 chord, but this chord doesn't resolve quite so nicely as the full B7 chord with the 5th in the chord. Does this chord still act like a dominant chord?

Answer (score 4):

B7 resolves most naturally to E.  So your (add 11th) chord is really just anticipating the resolution, which is totally fine-- in fact, it's a music technique.

If you want to really make a "thing" out of it, you can also keep the E in the bass over several chords in a row, whether it belongs to those chords or not.  That's something like a "pedal tone" from classical music.

**Short answer-- it's fine.  I bet it sounds nice.**

Comment: +1 for "pedal". More specifically, in this context, it's a tonic pedal. ("Tonic" refers to the pitch that is repeated -- in this case E.)

Answer (score 2):

It's not lack of 5th that causes issues, but coexistence of major 3rd and perfect 4th. Many musicians avoid this kind of sound, and perfect 4th is sometimes called an *avoid note* in a major chord. It goes beyond typical boundaries of functional harmony. Your chord: B-D#-E-A has an ambiguous identity – maybe it's a form of B chord, but maybe Emaj7sus4?

Concerning resolution, in a dominant 7th chord there are two tensions: 7th that requires resolving by a whole tone or half tone downwards and 3rd resolving by a half tone upwards, in your example from D# to E. In your chord note E is already present, so the resolution is much weaker.

Answer (score 1):

B7 is a dominant chord. Whatever else is added to it, it's still a dominant seventh chord. Maybe not sounding quite so pushy, but still dominant. Since the E is there already in the chord, as an 11th, it won't sound as direct when it gets to the E chord which often follows, as that note has been more than hinted at, but nevertheless, it's still a dominant seventh chord.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Does this chord still act like a dominant chord?"*

I tend to prefer a different question: *"**Can** this chord act like a dominant chord?"*

---

Adding the perfect 4th to a dominant seventh chord can be something of a bizarre idea to those raised on tertian harmonies, but it has its own different flavour. Personally, I like that kind of rubbing tension between the major third and perfect fourth of a chord, so to me, yes it can act as a dominant chord. Maybe for you or others, it sounds undesirable, and that's also fine.

I see no reason why it should lose its ability to serve as a dominant chord just because the chordal 4th anticipates the tonic note. The 13th of a dominant chord could be seen as an anticipation of the tonic chord's mediant, and I have yet to hear any complaints about dominant 13th chords being untowards. Now, the added note does **weaken** the chord's resolution, in all fairness. B7(11) is not nearly as directional as the regular dominant 7th chord (possibly smoothing the roughness of the tritone a bit via the chordal 4th forming a perfect 4th with the chordal 7th), and the chord also could have other situational interpretations on different roots or with different voicings: B7(11) = Emaj9sus = F#m7(11 13) = Amaj13(#11), et cetera. The exact chord names are unimportant, but its ambiguity could also play into the decreased strength of the resolution.

---

In my opinion, the most important factor towards whether something can work as a dominant chord is how one feels about the characteristics of its resolution to a tonic chord, as opposed to picking apart the intervals found within the chord. For example:

> Are suspended chords valid dominants? They don't contain the "dominant" major 3rd and minor 7th intervals, but work just fine in dominant positions. What about something like A/B (A9sus)? I'd call it a dominant, and the 5-1 motion in the bassline would tend to agree with me even though the chord spelled above that bassline is more typically understood as a plagal cadence. To me, even a voicing as outlandish as D#/B can function as a dominant chord going to E, even though spelled out in a chord label this would be E+maj7, which is not a dominant chord quality!

It will depend on what "dominant" means to each individual, but I would certainly not throw out the idea of using B7(11) in a dominant function simply because of the intervallic structure change! Use your ears, and if you like what you hear, make a little note of that and add it to your musical vocabulary. *Insert quote about great artists stealing here!*